# How can OpenMP be used inside Java code?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, openmp

I have a Java project, in which I have to achieve parallelization through OpenMP technology (that is, I have to, somehow, make a bridge between C/C++ and Java). So far I was told about using JNI for integrating C/C++ code in java, but, also I was suggested to use JaMP instead. I don't know much about these techniques/frameworks, so my question is, which is less pain to use, and, generally, how can I implement OpenMP stuff in Java code? Can I achieve the same functionality using only Java threads (without using OpenMP)? I'm a beginner in this domain, so absolutely any help is much appreciated.

Hint: the project is to build a collaborative graphic editor, by "putting" onto one core the interactions between the server and the clients, and "putting" onto another core the effective graphic processing.

Comment: Do you have to use OpenMP?  Why not use a Java based API/techniques for parallell processing?

Answer (score 5):

From your brief and slightly confusing explanation of your project I don't see any need for you to be using OpenMP at all.  All that you want to do can be done entirely within Java which has good (enough) facilities for concurrent programming.

OpenMP was designed for a completely different type of 'concurrent' program -- really for parallel programs; at its heart it's for spreading loop iterations across processors.  This is not a good fit to your problem.

If you have been told that you must use Java and OpenMP then I suppose you must.  If this is so, go with JaMP.  Only if someone holds a gun to your head should you set out on the path of Java+JNI+C/C+++OpenMp.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you tell me what would be the difficulties in using Java+JNI+C/C+++OpenMp? You're telling that is is unnecessary, or a real pain as well?

Comment: On the other hand, if you have some experience in JaMP, could you point me a good starting point to start learning? Is it Linux-only?

Comment: @twentynine -- Java+JNI+C/C+++OpenMP seems to be unnecessary for your purposes, and it will be a real pain -- you don't give the impression of someone who is comfortable with JNI, C/C++ and OpenMP -- trying to learn all 3 at the same time as you try to integrate them -- wy would you do that to yourself ?  No, I don't have experience of JaMP, I have used JOMP in the past, but JaMP seems more up to date and comes from a good stable.

Answer (score 0):

[Futures](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) can also be given a look for your project.
  Which I think is not used by many traditional programmers for parallelizing their work.